# Comobox's and executing Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, combobox

I want my code to be able to execute a command if the comboBox is equal to a certain variable. It's basically if combobox = 0 then excel will change the cell value to 0. The problem is that the if statement It is not properly formatted. Thanks for any help

```
        if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "0") 
        var xl = new Excel.Application(); 
        xl.Visible = true; 
        var wb = (Excel._Workbook)(xl.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value)); 
        var sheet = (Excel._Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet; 
        sheet.Cells[4, 6] = "0";
```

Comment: What is your exact error? You mention a *"`if` statement not properly formatted"* but you write *Excel* in your question title and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing {}. This shold be all right.

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "0")
{
    var xl = new Excel.Application(); 
    xl.Visible = true; 
    var wb = (Excel._Workbook)(xl.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value)); 
    var sheet = (Excel._Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet; 
    sheet.Cells[4, 6] = "0";
}
```

If there is more then one command following If statement, you have to use {}.

Comment: That's not the problem encountered by the PO I think.

Comment: There is few more options how to get value from combo, fell free use whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "0")
```

instead